# Windows 10 Extended Displays adjusting when I open applications

Tags: windows-10, extended-desktop

Whenever I open a new window, both my displays momentarily shrink a little and then size back.

So both monitors kinda reduce in size so there is a big black border, then after 1/2 a second they revert back to full monitor size.

This also happens when i minimize windows. In fact, the screen shrinks, then comes back and only then does the window minimise.

It may not sound like much but this is very annoying and happens on both my computers.

Any ideas on what is happening?

**edit**
It seems that when you, or at least I, have a Lenovo Yoga that rotates the screen this is an issue.  I unplugged the second monitor, noticed that the laptop switched to upside down mode, so I rotated the laptop around until the monitor swapped back to right way up, and then plugged the monitor in again and now the problem no longer happens.

Weird. Anyone know of a fix?